# Update wants to uninstall some packages

Tags: updates

I recently installed updates from the update manager. To my surprise I noticed that a bunch of installed applications were being removed.

The update was mainly some bug fixes for Compiz. There was no prior warning that these applications where to be removed in order to complete the update. Applications that were removed seemed to be everything I installed like Pidgin, Ardour, Webcam Studio, Sound indicator, most JACK related software.

Has anyone ever had a Similar  problem? I'm now scared to update. Was this a virus? What do I do?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are we talking about?

Comment: this is not  a virus
in compactable apps may removed during upgrading but will show the details before upgrading you may ignored it

Answer (score 0):

There is no virus, uninstalls and installs are part of the upgrade process.

Comment: but the OP seems to have lost full applications, not just certain outdated libraries which were replaced by newer ones.